# ckeditor onKeyUp event how?

Tags: javascript, html, events, ckeditor, onkeyup

This code piece must copy text from  textarea `text` to textarea `text_hidden`, this code work without ckeditor

`onKeyUp="document.getElementById('text_hidden').value = this.value;`

but when ckeditor enabled

`onKeyUp="document.getElementById('text_hidden').value = this.value;` not work.

How to fix this ?

```
<textarea name="text" id="text" rows="6" cols="80"  onKeyUp="document.getElementById('text_hidden').value = this.value;" ></textarea></p>

<textarea name="text_hidden" id="text_hidden" rows="6" cols="80" ></textarea>

<script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'text' ,
        {   
    allowedContent: true,
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,

    });
        CKFinder.SetupCKEditor( editor, '/ckfinder/' );
        config.startupPath = "/files/";
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my demo for CKEditor-to-textarea sync and vice versa: **https://jsfiddle.net/ty5ks393/1/**. Type in one of the three white boxes and see the content replicate across all four containers.

It uses Bootstrap to keep things tidy and shows both the classic and inline CKEditors. The pertinent parts (without external resources, comments and console.logs) are extracted here:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h2>TEXTAREA</h2>
            <textarea id="textarea" class="box"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h2>CK EDITOR INLINE</h2>
            <div contenteditable="true" id="contentedit" class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h2>CK EDITOR</h2>
            <textarea id="ckeditor" class="box"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h2>RESULT DIV</h2>
            <div id="result" class="box"></div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
    $(function() {
        CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
        var ce = CKEDITOR.inline("contentedit", {
            removePlugins: 'toolbar'
        });
        var ck = CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor').on('change', function(e) {
            if (document.activeElement.nodeName == "IFRAME") {
                var thisHTML = e.editor.getData();
                var tempDiv = $('<div>').html(thisHTML);
                thisText = tempDiv.text();
                $('#textarea').val(thisText);
                $('#contentedit, #result').html(thisHTML);  
            }
        });

        var timer;

        $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
            var _this = this;
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                var thisText =$(_this).val().replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
                $('#result, #contentedit').html(thisText);
                CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor.setData(thisText);
            }, 200);
        });

        $('#contentedit').keyup(function(e) {
            var _this = this;
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                var thisHTML = $(_this).html();
                var tempDiv = $('<div>').html(thisHTML.replace(/\<\/p\>/g,"</p>\n\n"));
                thisText = tempDiv.text();
                $('#textarea').val(thisText);
                $('#result').html(thisHTML);
                CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor.setData(thisHTML);
            }, 200);
        });
    });
```

So I use a timeout to avoid the bottlenecking that comes with keyup when using setData(). And I detect whether I am in an IFRAME to make sure I don't bounce content changes back out of the CKEditor when I've changed the content from one of the other containers using setData().

I hope it helps some of you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to synch WYSIWYG content with the textarea just tell the **on change** event as option to update the underlying element.

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
    on: {
          change: function() {
              this.updateElement();    
          }
    }
});
```

Comment: Mine didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

After searching around, I found an article ([ckeditor-keyup-event](http://blog-rat.blogspot.sg/2011/06/ckeditor-keyup-event.html)) stating that CKEditor api do not support "*keyup*" event.
Only on "*key*" method that listens to keypress event is supported.

The article author uses *editor.document.on('keyup')* in a callback on *editor.setData()*, which is only available after initialisation.

I prefer to attach the required keyup event during initialisation instead since his workaround does not work for my use case. I changed your code as shown below which works well for me although it is not actually attaching to a *keyup* event.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'text' ,
{   
    allowedContent: true,
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
}).on('key',
    function(e){
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('text_hidden').value = e.editor.getData();
        },10);
    }
);
```

**Without the *setTimeout()* function, *getData()* will not grab the last keystroke.**

Comment: This is such a common use case that it is ridiculous that keyup is not supported. They need to issue clear documentation and a Youtube video showing how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Having said that, I did get it working with keyup and without a setTimeout after much trial and error and Stackoverflow reading.

Comment: @MSC, can you post your working example? i would like to try it.

Comment: I'd recommend adding some kind of throttling function to that, this will take lots of CPU cycles from the browser if it actually executes the setTimeout after every single key; imagine typing fast - what will this do? I can imagine easily that two keystrokes come inside a 10ms window, so new timeouts might actually start after old timeouts are still waiting.